# How to make clearInterval work?

Tags: javascript

I can not figure out why clearInterval doesn't work below, Could anyone tell me what's the matter with my coding?

Thank you very much!

```
function timehandle(){
alert("Take a break")
}

setInterval(timehandle, 5000);
var getout=setInterval(timehandle, 5000);
var button=document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick=clearInterval(getout);
```

Comment: why two setInterval s? also `button.onclick=function(){clearInterval(getout);};`

Comment: Because you create 2 intervals. You cancel the 2nd but not the 1st.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a single interval and a function which calls `clearInterval`, because without, it clears the interval directly by assinging the return value of `clearInterval`.

BTW, it is usefull to use a different `id` of the tag, because some user agents use the id as variable name and it could be leading to conflicts by using own same named variables.

```js
function timehandle() {
    console.log("Take a break");
}

var getout = setInterval(timehandle, 5000);
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
button.onclick = function () { clearInterval(getout); };
```

```html
<button id="btn">clear</button>
```